# ERROR parsing data value of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, php, android, json

While Running the code (given after the error msg) throws the error as

Coding follows:

```
 public class Slide extends ActionBarActivity {
 private ProgressDialog pDialog;
 JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> detailsList;    //Creating a Arraylist
 private static String URL = "URL to my php page";
 private static final String TAG_DETAILS = "details";
 private static final String TAG_TITLE = "title";
 JSONArray details = null;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_slide);
    new onlineload().execute();             
}

class onlineload extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> 
{
    @Override 
     protected void onPreExecute() 
     { 
     super.onPreExecute(); 
     pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Slide.this); 
     pDialog.setMessage("Fetching Books..."); 
     pDialog.setIndeterminate(false); 
     pDialog.setCancelable(true); 
     pDialog.show(); 
     } 


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         String title = "";
          TextView tvTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Title);
          List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
          JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(URL, "GET", params);
          Log.d("All Products:",json.toString());
          try {
          details = json.getJSONArray(TAG_DETAILS);
          for (int i = 0; i < details.length(); i++) {
          JSONObject c = details.getJSONObject(i);
          title = title + c.getString(TAG_TITLE)+"\n";
          tvTitle.setText(title);
          }
          }
          catch (JSONException e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                  }
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Shown above is my java code..
Function of this code is to fetch Book title (more than 10 books title is available in database)from the online database and view it in an scroll view activity ..

my php code is working am getting the output only the problem is in displaying it in android activity !!

Looking for some help!!

JSON CODE:

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONArray jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET method
public JSONArray makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
List<NameValuePair> params) {

// Making HTTP request
try {

// check for request method
if(method == "POST"){
// request method is POST
// defaultHttpClient
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
is = httpEntity.getContent();

}else if(method == "GET"){
// request method is GET
Log.d("Entered Get", "Get SUccess"+url+method);
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
url += "?" + paramString;
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
is = httpEntity.getContent();
}   

} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}

try {
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
sb.append(line + "\n");
}
is.close();
json = sb.toString();

} catch (Exception e) {
Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
}

// try parse the string to a JSON object
try {
jObj = new JSONArray(json);
} catch (JSONException e) {
Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
}

// return JSON String
return jObj;

}
```

}

Comment: What do you think the error `Value of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject` is trying to tell you?

Comment: *type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject* means need to convert server response to JSONArray instead of JSONObject

Comment: *Sotirios Delimanolis what i understand is i cant convert an jsonarray to json object, actually i dono whr i did that conversion mistake ?!

Comment: * ρяσѕρєя K do u mean i need to change in my php code??

Comment: @Selvakumar: Also change `makeHttpRequest` method return type to JSONArray from JSONObject

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Sorry what to change in JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(URL, "GET", params);

Comment: @Selvakumar: I mean change `JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(URL, "GET", params);` to ` JSONArray json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(URL, "GET", params);`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK While changing that i get error in details=json.getJSONArray(TAG_DETAILS);

Comment: @Selvakumar: use `JSONObject details=json.getJSONObject(0);` or use for loop to get all object from json JSONArray

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK OMG Next error is on JSONObject c = details.getJSONObject(i);  i is of int type as used in for loop now the error is .getJSONObject is string cant pass int i argument

Answer (score 2):

```
Agree with @ρяσѕρєя K 

There was cast exception occurred that means you need to use JSON Array. Coz you are using JSON Object where actually JSON Array is required.

If you are confused within response which is receiving is JSONArray or JSONObject then you can go for get() method which return data in Object manner.

example :  Object c = details.get(i); 

So after that you can check for 

If(c instanceOf JSONArray){
/// perform as array operation
}


If(c instanceOf JSONObject){
// perform json object retrieving operation
}
```

Comment: Thank u for the support but am not aware where i need to do the corrections !!

Comment: ρяσѕρєя K  and @user2021595      
JSONArray details = null;
details = json.getJSONArray(TAG_DETAILS); error here is .getJSONArray should use int argument instead of "TAG_DETAILS" !!

Comment: well ill add my JSON code also few secs .. added above pls check the JSON CODE on top along with java code

Comment: This is low quality answer and adds nothing other users brought in their comments. Please rework your answer and either give more detailed solution to OP's question